# How to make the program window become active? - Python

Tags: python

So I have made a kind of reminder program.
it is like:

```
import time
task=input("Which Reminder Do You Want Me To Give you?     ")
print("After what time should i remind you   ")
timeh=int(input("Hour(s)   "))
timem=int(input("Minute(s)   "))
times=timeh*60*60+timem*60
if (timeh<0 & timem<0):
    print("Okay I will remind you after ",timeh," hour(s) and ",timem,"       minute(s). No worries")
    time.sleep(times)
    print("You had said ...",task,"... some ",timeh," hour(s) and ",timem," minute(s) earlier. Remember?")
elif (timeh==0):
    print("Okay I will remind you after ",timem," minute(s). No worries")
    time.sleep(times)
    print("You had said ...",task,"... some ",timem," minute(s) earlier. Remember?")
elif (timem==0):
    print("Okay I will remind you after ",timeh," hour(s). No worries")
    time.sleep(times)
    print("You had said ...",task,"... some ",timeh," hour(s) earlier. Remember?")
```

How can i make the window become active when the program has become active again?

Comment: IMHO, this depends on GUI subsystem of Os you are using. In case of Windows you'll have to send some windows messages (WM_XXXXX) to a certain window. For UNIX/Linux this will depend on Window Manager.